Printer homes X, Y then Z in the middle of the bed, but then sets the origin to the middle of the bed
I have a Creality CR10-S5.  It homes the X and Y axes then homes to Z in the middle of the bed.  The origin location is set at the front left of the bed.  It homes great, but it also resets the origin to the middle of the bed when I try to print so when it starts the Z probing for autolevel it starts in the middle and then runs off the right side of the bed.
Here is my Start G-code:
G75 ; Start Print Timer and Engage Fil Sensor
G28 ; home all axes
G29 ; auto bed leveling
G4 S10; wait for heaters to recover
;M92 E144.927
M117 Purging Extruder...
G1 Z1.0 F3000 ; lift Z
G1 X20.2 Y25 Z0.2 F3000.0 ; move to start-line position
G92 E0 ; reset extruder
G1 X20.2 Y150.0 F1000.0 E15 ; draw 1st line
G1 X20.7 Y150.0 F3000.0 ; move to side 0.5mm
G1 X20.7 Y50 F1000.0 E30 ; draw 2nd line
G1 X20.7 Y25 F5000.0 ; quick wipe

Is there anything wrong with my startup script?






Here is my M501:
READ: echo:V76 stored settings retrieved (692 bytes; crc 56607)
V76 stored settings retrieved (692 bytes; crc 56607)
READ: echo:  G21    ; Units in mm (mm)
G21    ; Units in mm (mm)
READ: echo:  M149 C ; Units in Celsius
M149 C ; Units in Celsius
READ: 
READ: echo:; Filament settings: Disabled
; Filament settings: Disabled
READ: echo:  M200 D1.75
M200 D1.75
READ: echo:  M200 D0
M200 D0
READ: echo:; Steps per unit:
; Steps per unit:
READ: echo: M92 X80.00 Y80.00 Z400.00 E415.00
M92 X80.00 Y80.00 Z400.00 E415.00
READ: echo:; Maximum feedrates (units/s):
; Maximum feedrates (units/s):
READ: echo:  M203 X500.00 Y500.00 Z5.00 E25.00
M203 X500.00 Y500.00 Z5.00 E25.00
READ: echo:; Maximum Acceleration (units/s2):
; Maximum Acceleration (units/s2):
READ: echo:  M201 X500.00 Y500.00 Z100.00 E5000.00
M201 X500.00 Y500.00 Z100.00 E5000.00
READ: echo:; Acceleration (units/s2): P<print_accel> R<retract_accel> T<travel_accel>
; Acceleration (units/s2): P<print_accel> R<retract_accel> T<travel_accel>
READ: echo:  M204 P500.00 R500.00 T1000.00
M204 P500.00 R500.00 T1000.00
READ: echo:; Advanced: B<min_segment_time_us> S<min_feedrate> T<min_travel_feedrate> X<max_x_jerk> Y<max_y_jerk> Z<max_z_jerk> E<max_e_jerk>
; Advanced: B<min_segment_time_us> S<min_feedrate> T<min_travel_feedrate> X<max_x_jerk> Y<max_y_jerk> Z<max_z_jerk> E<max_e_jerk>
READ: echo:  M205 B20000.00 S0.00 T0.00 X5.00 Y5.00 Z0.40 E5.00
M205 B20000.00 S0.00 T0.00 X5.00 Y5.00 Z0.40 E5.00
READ: echo:; Home offset:
; Home offset:
READ: echo:  M206 X0.00 Y0.00 Z0.00
M206 X0.00 Y0.00 Z0.00
READ: echo:; Auto Bed Leveling:
; Auto Bed Leveling:
READ: echo:  M420 S0 Z2.00
M420 S0 Z2.00
READ: echo:  G29 W I0 J0 Z-0.07204
G29 W I0 J0 Z-0.07204
READ: echo:  G29 W I1 J0 Z-0.11914
G29 W I1 J0 Z-0.11914
READ: echo:  G29 W I2 J0 Z-0.07452
G29 W I2 J0 Z-0.07452
READ: echo:  G29 W I3 J0 Z0.14611
G29 W I3 J0 Z0.14611
READ: echo:  G29 W I4 J0 Z-0.25548
G29 W I4 J0 Z-0.25548
READ: echo:  G29 W I0 J1 Z-0.06708
G29 W I0 J1 Z-0.06708
READ: echo:  G29 W I1 J1 Z-0.05221
G29 W I1 J1 Z-0.05221
READ: echo:  G29 W I2 J1 Z-0.00015
G29 W I2 J1 Z-0.00015
READ: echo:  G29 W I3 J1 Z0.12876
G29 W I3 J1 Z0.12876
READ: echo:  G29 W I4 J1 Z-0.21829
G29 W I4 J1 Z-0.21829
READ: echo:  G29 W I0 J2 Z0.02216
G29 W I0 J2 Z0.02216
READ: echo:  G29 W I1 J2 Z0.04943
G29 W I1 J2 Z0.04943
READ: echo:  G29 W I2 J2 Z0.04943
G29 W I2 J2 Z0.04943
READ: echo:  G29 W I3 J2 Z0.19569
G29 W I3 J2 Z0.19569
READ: echo:  G29 W I4 J2 Z-0.11170
G29 W I4 J2 Z-0.11170
READ: echo:  G29 W I0 J3 Z0.12628
G29 W I0 J3 Z0.12628
READ: echo:  G29 W I1 J3 Z0.19073
G29 W I1 J3 Z0.19073
READ: echo:  G29 W I2 J3 Z0.31715
G29 W I2 J3 Z0.31715
READ: echo:  G29 W I3 J3 Z0.47333
G29 W I3 J3 Z0.47333
READ: echo:  G29 W I4 J3 Z0.27005
G29 W I4 J3 Z0.27005
READ: echo:  G29 W I0 J4 Z0.15354
G29 W I0 J4 Z0.15354
READ: echo:  G29 W I1 J4 Z0.38656
G29 W I1 J4 Z0.38656
READ: echo:  G29 W I2 J4 Z0.57000
G29 W I2 J4 Z0.57000
READ: echo:  G29 W I3 J4 Z0.75592
G29 W I3 J4 Z0.75592
READ: echo:  G29 W I4 J4 Z0.52043
G29 W I4 J4 Z0.52043
READ: echo:; Material heatup parameters:
; Material heatup parameters:
READ: echo:  M145 S0 H195 B60 F0
M145 S0 H195 B60 F0
READ: echo:  M145 S1 H225 B70 F0
M145 S1 H225 B70 F0
READ: echo:; PID settings:
; PID settings:
READ: echo:  M301 P22.20 I1.08 D114.00
M301 P22.20 I1.08 D114.00
READ: echo:; Z-Probe Offset (mm):
; Z-Probe Offset (mm):
READ: echo:  M851 X38.00 Y-4.00 Z-0.90
M851 X38.00 Y-4.00 Z-0.90
READ: echo:; Linear Advance:
; Linear Advance:
READ: echo:  M900 K0.22
M900 K0.22
READ: echo:; Filament load/unload lengths:
; Filament load/unload lengths:
READ: echo:  M603 L600.00 U750.00
M603 L600.00 U750.00
READ: echo:; Filament runout sensor:
; Filament runout sensor:
READ: echo:  M412 S1
M412 S1
READ: ok P15 B3
READ: ok T:29.60 /0.00 B:34.58 /0.00 @:0 B@:0


How did you setup your slicer? Also front left, not in the center? Having the origin in the center is rare, but there are a few brands that do that (e.g. Delta kinematics). Post images of your slicer configuration please.

Another thing to note: If the bed is not on the limit switches when I turn it on and I use the knobs to select home all axis, the Y heads towards the front instead of the back where the limit switch is installed.  If I push the bed to the Y limit switch and then turn the printer on and select home all it homes correctly.  I can then get it to print as long as I comment out the G29 in the startup script.

Basically, your question is: "Why does my bed home in the incorrect direction?". You need to first plug off the mains power, unplug the stepper plug at the board or at the stepper and reverse the plug by turning it 180°. Now the direction of the Y stepper is changed and homing will be correct. Did this always do this? Or has something changed?

The issue with my G29 still stands too.  My comment is how I have to get it to home properly with the "safe z homing" in the center of the bed, but then the G29 makes the center of the bed the new 0,0,0 point.  I may have two different issues.  The printer used to work great.  I just haven't used it in about a year and just starting it back up, it has these issues.

Are you sure nothing changed like wiring, e.g. homing is a firmware instruction, if it goes the wrong way when homing it implies the connections are switched or the firmware has changed. The latter is something you should know. I'd start with identifying if all axes run the correct direction. Before tackling other issues.

Would the Y axis still move in the correct direction using the manual move if the connection was switched?  I know nothing has changed in the firmware.

Ah, I just hooked the printer up to my computer and sent an M119, with the bed pushed into the sensor and off of the sensor.  The M119 showed triggered both times.  I even unplugged the sensor and sent an M119 command and it showed triggered....

Then you have an endstop that fails, replace the cables. A failing endstop will prevent movement to the endstop!

It is finally fixed.  Cables were good, switches were good. I ended up taking the control box apart and found the the y connected became disconnected on the inside. Cut the zip tie, gave it more slack and put it back together.  Runs great!

Glad you fixed it! Loose cable after all, albeit a different one. Please write an answer, please don't answer in the comments, comments may be deleted in time. Don't forget to accept your answer by clicking the checkmark 48 hours after posting the answer!
